# Get data from 2 different databases on 2 different servers and join them using C#

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2012, ado.net

I want to get data from 2 different database instances located on 2 different servers respectively and apply a join query on the returned resultsets(2) in C#. I'm not supposed to use linked servers due to security concerns and would like to apply the join in C# on 2 result sets returned from the 2 database servers.

Please suggest optimal solutions for this and any working examples.
Note : I need to prepare XML data out of the resultant resultset after joining both the resultsets.

Comment: I cannot access the second database in the query as there is no linked server. How can i write a view if in case i cannot access the second database. I've also looked into OpenRowSet, which needs permission. Instead of OpenRowSet, How good it will be if get data from 2 databases and join them with filter criteria using LINQ? Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's way broad question but rough idea

you can create two custom classes for those tables

Fetch data from both server and fill the class objects separately. Which will get you `List<customentity>`

If both table has common column or any relationship between them, then you can join both the custom entities on that common column.

Not sure why can't you use `linked server` since this are specific situation why `linked servers` have been introduced and helpful for.

Comment: There is a relationship between the two tables, After getting the first data from first server, I need to join the second server with first server's Primary key..

Comment: @PuliganP, Ok, see answer steps ... you have no other way than getting then separately, fill the custom classes/models and then perform join.

Comment: Can i prepare XML from the list data?

Comment: @PuliganP, yes definitely you can,

Comment: or, as a variant of this technique, fetch the data from the first server into List<fullInfo>, extract primary keys into List<pkinfo>, then pass that list to the second server as a table valued parameter to a stored proc etc. This <i>may</i> be more efficient if the second server only needs to return a smaller subset of data, but it depends on your join.